# Postgres - relallvisible is 0 after one day

Tags: database, postgresql

we had problem with performance on table, So I found that relavisible was 0 and relpage around 1000000. I did VACUUM ANALYZE and everything started to working fine but after one day relavisible for this table back to 0. Why this happend? We keep this table as archive so only once a day we move data from orginal table to that one using a simple function. One of solution may be do VACUUM ANALYZE after function but I don't want to do it. I think that postgres should handle this problem on his own. I understand that after some time table again will have 0 relavisible but no after one day where table is around 10m rows and we copy 15-20k rows per day.

Answer (score 1):

That is not normal.  Most likely someone did something to the table, like VACUUM FULL or CLUSTER or a bulk UPDATE, which cleared the visibility map.

It is possible each block had a bit of freespace in it, and those got filled up by the next bulk insert.  But if that is the case, now that the space is full it shouldn't happen again.  Unless whatever created the scattered free space happens again.